# Putting formula in cell with Powershell

Tags: excel, powershell-2.0

I have an issue putting a formula in an excel cell. The formula contains a variable.

```
$batchname = Batch15c

$ws.Cells.Item(2,5).value() = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],[$batchname]Sheet1!$A$1:$D$300,2,FALSE)
```

I get the following error:

```
-Exception setting "Value": "Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC"
```

anybody got any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I believe should be setting the `Formula` property instead of `Value`.

Try:

```
 $ws.Cells.Item(2,5).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],[$batchname]Sheet1!$A$1:$D$300,2,FALSE)"
```