# Insert complicated Excel formula using Powershell

Tags: excel, powershell, excel-formula

Here is original article: [link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22859584/putting-formula-in-cell-with-powershell)

**Now my question:**

Using the .formula, I can get very far, but I have a very complicated formula and it doesn't want to work.

The code that works in Excel:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(G2),"",VLOOKUP("*"&LEFT(G2,9)&"*",'\\compname\path\to\excel\[ramdata.xlsx]20151009'!A:B,2,FALSE))
```

The code that does not work in Powershell:

```
$ws.Cells.Item($intRow,9).Formula = '=VLOOKUP("*"$([char]38)LEFT(G$intRow,5)$([char]38)"*",'\\compname\path\to\excel\[ramdata.xlsx]20151009'!A:B,2,FALSE)'
```

After I run the powershell script, the cell in which I am inserting the formula is blank.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was so close and needed to ask for help to find the answer!

```
$ws.Cells.Item($intRow,9).Formula = "=IF(ISBLANK(G$intRowMem),$([char]34)$([char]34),VLOOKUP($([char]34)*$([char]34)&LEFT(G$intRowMem,5)&$([char]34)*$([char]34),'\\compname\path\to\excel\[ramdata.xlsx]20151009'!A:B,2,FALSE))"
```

Is it ethical to answer your own question and mark your answer as the answer?

**EDIT**

Per @TheMadTechnician, this can also be solved as:

```
$ws.Cells.Item($intRow,9).Formula = "=IF(ISBLANK(G$intRowMem),`"`",VLOOKUP(`"*`"&LEFT(G$intRowMem,5)&`"*`",'\\compname\path\to\excel\[ramdata.xlsx]20151009'!A:B,2,FALSE))"
```

Comment: Wow, you went through a lot of trouble to get those double quotes in there... in the future you can just escape them with a backtick (\`) within your string to get them there, or double them up such as `"The path ""C:\Temp"" doesn't actually need quotes around it"` will appear as `The path "c:\temp" doesn't actually need quotes around it`. And it's just fine to accept your own answer if it actually answers the question.

Comment: I had used the backtick, but did not think it worked. What really happened is that I was trying to many things at once. I did try it and LONG and BEHOLD it worked just fine.

Comment: You can do it but you need to wait a bit: http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: I know this is an old one by now, but THANK YOU! - Been pulling my hair for hours trying to figure this out! - i had tried the approach  using ´"´"
But didn't realize I had used the incorrect character to escape (´ instead of `)